# Images not rendering in IE7 (but working fine in IE6/Firefox)

Tags: image, internet-explorer-7

Having an issue with some images using IE7 - work fine in 6 and in all versions of Firefox.

Has anyone run across this before? I know I've had it happen in the past (and I googled a fix, but darned if I can find the fix again... note to self, document things like this for future ;) )

```
<div class="contextBlock">
<p class="cntImg"><a href="files/image.jsp" title="Image"><img src="files/images/image.jpg" alt="Image" width="171" height="96" border="0">Image</a></p>
<p class="cntImg"><a href="files/image2.jsp" title="image2"><img src="files/images/image2.jpg" alt="Image2" width="171" height="96" border="0">Image2 </a></p>
<p class="comment">Click to enlarge</p>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I've come across this type of problem before when images uploaded to our site were JPEGs in [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) format - Internet explorer would show them as a small red x, but Firefox would show them OK (definitely as of version 3, not sure about earlier releases).

Could you post the css rules for `contextBlock`, `cntImg` and `clr`? Another "funny" IE thing I've come across in the past is images disappearing behind a text block which has a css style that IE doesn't like, so I'm wondering if this might be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Great thought PConroy. We were trying to debug our Web application and had images not showing up. Indeed, it was the RGB/CMYK issue. IE 7 does not render CMYK format JPG's.

Answer (score 2):

Two things that *might* help:

1. close your img tags with />
2. try removing the text from your links

your links should look kinda like this:

```
<a href="files/image.jsp" title="Image">
  <img src="files/images/image.jpg" alt="Image" width="171" height="96" border="0" />
</a>
```

It's possible that this could be caused by your DOCTYPE. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup the colorspace of an image:

`identify -verbose MattCutts.jpg | grep Colorspace`

Colorspace: CMYK

Then, convert image to RGB colorspace (can also use *.jpg etc.)

`mogrify -colorspace rgb MattCutts.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past running the page locally on my machine with IE7. That could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the space for the images being allocated yet the images are not showing up?

Is it possible that other markup on the page is covering the space that the images should appear?

Are you familiar with the [web developer toolbar for IE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)?

I think it is likely that the images are being rendered and that you can't see them because something else is covering them or the markup of the container they are in is causing it to not be visible.

Good luck.